# Rate calculation for sparse coding (significance coding)

Tags: coding-theory

How can I establish the approximate equality below?

Let $M \ll N$ be the number of significant coefficients that is coded with $\log N$ bits. There are $\binom{N}{M}$ different sets of $M$ coefficients chosen among $N$. To code an approximation support of the $M$ coded coefficients without any other prior information requires a number of bits:

$R_0 = \log_2 N + \log_2$ $\binom{N}{M}$ $\approx M\left(1 + \log_2\frac{N}{M}\right)$

Comment: Link to [Stephane Mallat's book](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=5qzeLJljuLoC&lpg=PA510&ots=97kkugI17v&dq=wavelet%20tour%20geometric%20bit%20budget&pg=PA510#v=onepage&q=wavelet%20tour%20geometric%20bit%20budget&f=false)

Answer (score 0):

Fix $M$. Take $f(N) = \log_2(N) + \log_2 \binom{N}{M}$ and $g(N) = M(1+\log_2(\frac{N}{M})$. Clearly,

$$
\lim_\limits{N \to +\infty} f(N) = \lim_\limits{N \to +\infty} g(N) = +\infty
$$

Apply L'Hopital's rule:

$$
\lim_\limits{N \to +\infty} \frac{f'(N)}{g'(N)} = \frac{M+1}{M} \approx 1
$$

This doesn't really give any insight as to where the approximation on the right arises though. Perhaps it could be better established through some combinatorial argument?

Comment: Thanks Chester. I think it should be possible to derive an approximation $\widehat{R_0}(M) = M(1+\log_2 \frac{N}{M})$ by fixing $N$ instead? I tried to use Stirling's formula, but haven't been able to derive the above approximation.

Comment: @JohnLee, You mean apply Stirling's in the LHS in the $N!$ or $(N-M)!$ terms? I tried that at first as well, but it didn't really seem to get anywhere.

Comment: Another thing to notice is that $$LHS = \log_2(N) + \log_2(N(N-1)...(N-M+1)) - \log_2(M!) \\ \approx \log_2(N) + \log_2(N^M) - \log_2(M!)$$  But then if you compare the $LHS$ with the $RHS$, it requires that $$\log_2(N) - \log_2(M!) \approx M - M \log_2M$$
which doesn't really seem to make sense...